# with clause in a function for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to query a table using the 'with' clause inside a function using PostgreSQL. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

I tried returning the table but it's saying that the column names are ambiguous.

Comment: With the information given, the only answer possible is: "don't use ambiguous column names"

Comment: I think you mean a `with cte_name(column_alias1,column_alias1) as (select a.same_name,b.same_name from t1)` type of construction. Alternatively you can alias the columns inside the cte `with cte_name as (select a.same_name as "A", b.same_name as "B" from t1)`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-D5Ud8Hm)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please don't forget to vote to close

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL requires knowing the exact structure of the returned data.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
 RETURNS TABLE(id integer, caption text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin

    return query
    with tb (a1, a2) as (
      values 
        (1, 'Test 1'),
        (2, 'Test 2'),
        (3, 'Test 3'),
        (4, 'Test 4')
    )
    select tb.a1, tb.a2 from tb; 
 
end ;
$function$
;
```

And fixing - column names are ambiguous - problem recommended use table name aliases inside the function and select columns with aliases.